# Drawing a circle with radial lines

Tags: vb6, drawing, rounding, user-experience

```
for i = 0 to 23

   '' ...
   '' create 'line' control
   '' ...

   line.x1 = (inner_radius*cos(15 * i)) + centerx
   line.y1 = (inner_radius*sin(15 * i)) + centery
   line.x2 = (outer_radius*cos(15 * i)) + centerx
   line.y2 = (outer_radius*sin(15 * i)) + centery

next
```

I'm using this algorithm to render many line controls to make something like the following:

[image]

The result is rather bizarre:

[image]

I think this happens due to the rounding of the cos() and sin() functions, so my question is, is there some algorithm I can apply to fix the rounding? Or is there a better way to render such controls, perhaps?

**EDIT:**

The problem, as pointed by Hrqls was that I was using degrees instead of radians... this is the function that I ended up using:

```
Sub ProgressAnim(ByVal centerx, _
                 ByVal centery, _
                 ByVal outer_radius, _
                 ByVal inner_radius, _
                 ByVal step_count, _
                 ByVal line_width)

    Dim pi
    Dim degstep
    Dim scan
    Dim newcontrol As Line
    Dim controlid

    pi = 4 * Atn(1)
    degstep = pi / (step_count / 2)

    For scan = 0 To step_count - 1

        controlid = "line" & (scan + 1)

        Set newcontrol = Me.Controls.Add("vb.line", controlid)

        newcontrol.X1 = centerx + (inner_radius * Cos(degstep * scan))
        newcontrol.Y1 = centery + (inner_radius * Sin(degstep * scan))
        newcontrol.X2 = centerx + (outer_radius * Cos(degstep * scan))
        newcontrol.Y2 = centery + (outer_radius * Sin(degstep * scan))
        newcontrol.BorderStyle = 1
        newcontrol.BorderWidth = line_width
        newcontrol.Visible = True

    Next

End Sub
```

Calling it like this

```
ProgressAnim 150, 250, 16, 9, 18, 1
```

produces this:

[image]

which is much closer to what I expected... sadly, I still don't know how to achieve anti-aliasing, but this will do. (For the moment, at least) :)

Comment: please post your variables declarations ... what are the types of your variables? ... use "option explicit" at the top of all your form codes and modules to ensure you declare all variables

Comment: Well, the types of the variables are Variant, but I was completely in the wrong track... the problem was that I was using degs instead of rads.

Comment: I was on the wrong track as well, until i printed the numbers at the end of the lines .. this showed me that the lines werent printed in the order i assumed, but skipped large parts of the circle and in fact went around the circle a couple of times .. thus the angle-step was too large :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you calculate the angles in degrees while VB uses radians for its angles

have a look at the following project :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Click()
  DrawWheel
End Sub

Private Sub DrawWheel()
  Dim intI As Integer
  Dim sngRadius As Single
  Dim sngRadiusY As Single
  Dim sngCenterX As Single, sngCenterY As Single
  Dim sngX1 As Single, sngY1 As Single
  Dim sngX2 As Single, sngY2 As Single
  Dim sngStep As Single
  Dim sngAngle As Single
  Dim sngCos As Single, sngSin As Single
  'calculate form sizes
  sngRadius = (ScaleWidth - 240) / 2
  sngRadiusY = (ScaleHeight - 240) / 2
  sngCenterX = 120 + sngRadius
  sngCenterY = 120 + sngRadiusY
  If sngRadiusY < sngRadius Then sngRadius = sngRadiusY
  'draw circle
  Circle (sngCenterX, sngCenterY), sngRadius
  'calculate step between lines
  sngStep = Atn(1) / 3
  'draw lines
  For intI = 0 To 23
    'calculate angle for each line
    sngAngle = sngStep * intI
    'calculate coordinates for each line
    sngCos = Cos(sngAngle)
    sngSin = Sin(sngAngle)
    sngX1 = sngCenterX + sngCos * sngRadius / 10
    sngY1 = sngCenterY + sngSin * sngRadius / 10
    sngX2 = sngCenterX + sngCos * sngRadius
    sngY2 = sngCenterY + sngSin * sngRadius
    'draw each lines
    Line (sngX1, sngY1)-(sngX2, sngY2)
    'print sequence number
    Print CStr(intI)
  Next intI
End Sub
```

Click on the form to draw the wheel

Atn(1) is PI/4 ... For 24 lines you need to divide 2*PI by 24 .. thus you need to divide PI by 12 ... which makes you divide Atn(1) by 3

Comment: * facepalm * ...degrees instead of radians... I whish VB6 intellisense was clearer... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `for i = 0 to 23` to `for i = 0 to 21`
and `(15 * i)` with `(0.3 * i)`

Try that code in form1 with a timer1:

```
Dim c As Integer, centerx As Integer, centery As Integer, inner_radius As Integer, outer_radius As Integer
Dim x1 As Single, y1 As Single, x2 As Single, y2 As Single
Private Sub Form_Load()
    c = 0
    centerx = Form1.Width / 2
    centery = Form1.Height / 2
    inner_radius = 1200
    outer_radius = 1
    Timer1.Interval = 200
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    x1 = (inner_radius * Cos(0.3 * c)) + centerx
    y1 = (inner_radius * Sin(0.3 * c)) + centery
    x2 = (outer_radius * Cos(0.3 * c)) + centerx
    y2 = (outer_radius * Sin(0.3 * c)) + centery
    Line (x1, y1)-(x2, y2), RGB(0, 0, 0)
    c = c + 1
    If c = 21 Then Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

check your numbers in this example to see the drawing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that you keep the greatest accuracy by using proper fractions of 2PI.

Fiddle with the constants until you get roughly what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Timer.Interval = 50
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Timer()
    DrawRadialLines
End Sub

Private Sub DrawRadialLines()

    Const ksngPI            As Single = 3.14159!
    Const ksngCircle        As Single = 2! * ksngPI

    Const ksngInnerRadius   As Single = 130!
    Const ksngOuterRadius   As Single = 260!

    Const ksngCenterX       As Single = 1200!
    Const ksngCenterY       As Single = 1200!

    Const klSegmentCount    As Long = 12

    Const klLineWidth       As Long = 3

    Static s_lActiveSegment As Integer              ' The "selected" segment.

    Dim lSegment            As Long
    Dim sngRadians          As Single
    Dim sngX1               As Single
    Dim sngY1               As Single
    Dim sngX2               As Single
    Dim sngY2               As Single
    Dim cLineColour         As OLE_COLOR

    Me.DrawWidth = klLineWidth

    ' Overdraw previous graphic.
    Me.Line (ksngCenterX - ksngOuterRadius - Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 2, ksngCenterY - ksngOuterRadius - Screen.TwipsPerPixelY * 2)-(ksngCenterX + ksngOuterRadius + Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 2, ksngCenterY + ksngOuterRadius + Screen.TwipsPerPixelY * 2), Me.BackColor, BF

    For lSegment = 0 To klSegmentCount - 1

        '
        ' Work out the coordinates for the line to be draw from the outside circle to the inside circle.
        '

        sngRadians = (ksngCircle * CSng(lSegment)) / klSegmentCount

        sngX1 = (ksngOuterRadius * Cos(sngRadians)) + ksngCenterX
        sngY1 = (ksngOuterRadius * Sin(sngRadians)) + ksngCenterY
        sngX2 = (ksngInnerRadius * Cos(sngRadians)) + ksngCenterX
        sngY2 = (ksngInnerRadius * Sin(sngRadians)) + ksngCenterY

        ' Work out how many segments away from the "current segment" we are.
        ' The current segment should be the darkest, and the further away from this segment we are, the lighter the colour should be.
        Select Case Abs(Abs(s_lActiveSegment - lSegment) - klSegmentCount \ 2)
        Case 0!
            cLineColour = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case 1!
            cLineColour = RGB(63, 63, 255)
        Case 2!
            cLineColour = RGB(117, 117, 255)
        Case Else
            cLineColour = RGB(181, 181, 255)
        End Select

        Me.Line (sngX1, sngY1)-(sngX2, sngY2), cLineColour

    Next lSegment

    ' Move the current segment on by one.
    s_lActiveSegment = (s_lActiveSegment + 1) Mod klSegmentCount

End Sub
```